# SQL use MAX() function select field not in Group By

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, max

I want to find the most recent entry for a unique combination of two fields in my table.

```
Employee_Number | Cap_Id | Score | Date_Added
```

I want to find the most recent 'Date_Added' for a group of Employee_Number and Cap_Id but also show the 'Score' entered for that group. I can Group By Employee_Number and Cap_Id to get the row I want in the result, but I can't also show the Score as Group By will determine it as a distinct value.

If my table looks like:

```
Employee_Number Cap_Id  Score   Date_Added
96149             2       4     04/06/2015
96149             2       3     03/06/2015
```

I want the result to be:

```
Employee_Number Cap_Id  Score   Date_Added
96149             2       4     04/06/2015
```

I can use:

```
SELECT Employee_Number, Cap_Id, MAX(Date_Added)
FROM Scores
GROUP BY Employee_Number, Cap_Id
```

To get the correct result, but I need the Score too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the `GROUP BY`, return a row if no other row with same `Employee_Number` and `Cap_Id` but a later date exists!

```
SELECT Employee_Number, Cap_Id, Score, Date_Added
FROM Scores s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Scores s2
                  where s1.Employee_Number = s2.Employee_Number
                    and s1.Cap_Id = s2.Cap_Id
                    and s1.Date_Added < s2.Date_Added)
```

It'll return both rows if there's a tie!

**Edit** - some kind of explanation:

The sub-query looks for another row with same `Employee_Number` and `Cap_Id`, but a later `Date_Added` value.

If no such row exists, the row from the main select is returned.

What to select in the sub-select is of no importance, the important thing is if a row `exists` or `not exists`. (That's the `select 1`. You can select whatever in the sub-query, if doesn't matter.)

Comment: No idea how this works but it did, thank you! Could you explain what's happening with the 'Select 1 from...' expression?

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need **Group by** there.

```
SELECT Employee_Number, Cap_Id, Score, Date_Added
FROM Scores
WHERE MAX(Date_Added) = Date_Added
```

You also can try this if Access doesn't allow you to Use **max()** in where clause.

```
SELECT Employee_Number, Cap_Id, Score, Date_Added
FROM Scores AS s1
WHERE  Date_Added = (SELECT MAX(Date_Added) FROM Scores s2 where s1.Employee_Number =  s2.Employee_Number)
```

Comment: Forgot to say, I'm using Access and I don't think WITH(NOLOCK) is supported. What is that doing in any case?

Comment: But I'm told I can't use the aggregate function in the WHERE clause

Comment: @user3804579 I have modified, check this

Comment: Thanks, that also works (i just needed to add an addition AND to the WHERE clause for the Cap_Id matching)